# 404 Not Found: Something wrong with access to a servlet deployed on Tomcat

Tags: java, spring, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I followed a very simple example from Head First Servlets & JSP at beginning, but I encountered a problem. When I tried to access a servlet named `Ch1Servlet` in webapps/ch1/web-inf/, mapped onto url-pattern:/Serv1, tomcat returned ERROR 404:

```
HTTP Status 404 - /ch1/Serv1
```

I typed localhost:8080 into address bar of my browser, and it showed the home page of Tomcat, which seemed to be OK with the server.
Then I created a servlet named `Ch1Servlet`. Here is what it looks like:

```
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Ch1Servlet extends HttpServlet{
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException{
        PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
        java.util.Date today=new java.util.Date();
        out.println("<html><body><h1>Today</h1>"+today+"</body></html>");
    }
}
```

Next, a web.xml configuration file is needed. So here is it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <Servlet>
        <Servlet-name>Ch1Servlet</Servlet-name>
        <Servlet-class>Ch1Servlet</Servlet-class>
    </Servlet>

    <Servlet-mapping>
        <Servlet-name>Ch1Servlet</Servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/Serv1</url-pattern>
    </Servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

After Ch1Servlet.java was compiled, I got a class file which was put in WEB-INF/classes, and put the web.xml in WEB-INF. So the hierarchy is this: webapps/ch1/WEB-INF.

It suggested that we will be able to access the servlet and get a HTML page displayed on the screen, by using the url: http://localhost:8080/ch1/Serv1. But unfortunately, ERROR 404 was found there.

Answer (score 1):

All the xml elements in web.xml should start with lowercase letters.

Answer (score -1):

In `web.xml` you are not defining the full path of the class:

```
<Servlet>
    <Servlet-name>Ch1Servlet</Servlet-name>
    <Servlet-class>com.test.Ch1Servlet</Servlet-class>
</Servlet>
```

`com.test.` is the package name of `Ch1Servlet` class. Please use full path to classes.

Comment: No package name is stated anywhere in the question.